# Are these instructions simply telling me to declare a global variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

The instructions are: "Below the declaration for the httpRequest variable, add a statement declaring a variable with the name countrySel." Does this just mean I need to declare a global variable? I posted my code below. Did I do this correctly? The wording of the instructions is confusing me.

```
// global variable which can potentially hold multiple AJAX requests
var httpRequest = false;
var countrySel;
```

I apologize for this basic of a question. I am very new to coding and computer programming.

Comment: i think that's correct, enjoy coding!

Comment: Back in the old days, it took a dozen-line function to properly get the httpRequest variable and some folks would just use a single global value.  In modern coding, that is no longer needed and a bad idea anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The wording implies that you need to add another variable in the same scope as your `httpRequest` variable. The variable may not be global, as if it is in a function it will then only be available inside that function. If you are working in global scope then your assumption seems correct.